# Función recursiva para recorrer objeto

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente ejercicio

Implementar la función objContains: debe buscar dentro de un objeto anidado un par {clave: valor} especifico. Tanto el objeto como el nombre de la propiedad y su valor serán recibidos por parámetro. En el caso de que encuentre el valor indicado en cualquier nivel del objeto debe devolver true, de lo contrario, devolver false.

El codigo que tengo hecho es el siguiente:

```
var objContains = function (obj, prop, value) {
  for (propiedad in obj) {
    if (propiedad === prop && obj[propiedad] === value) {
      return true;
    } else if (typeof obj[propiedad] === 'object') {
      obj = obj[propiedad];
      objContains(obj, prop, value);
    }
    return false;
  }   
}
```

el objeto es este:

```
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      },
    },
  };
```

Y las ejecuciones son:

```
objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield") // Al ejecutar esta el resultado debe ser true

objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear");// al ejecutar esta debe ser false
```

Cuando ejecuto la funcion que debe dar false funciona todo bien pero cuando ejecuto la que debe dar true el resultado es false.

Me podrian decir en que estoy fallando gracias;

Comment: Podés [edit] tu pregunta e insertar un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para poder reproducir el problema en la propia pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el problema que tienes es que estas retornando `false` en la primera iteracion, y además cuando la propiedad es un objeto, debes no solo ejecutar `objContains`, sino devolver su resultado.

Te dejo el código corregido:

```js
const user = {
    id: 6,
    email: "homero@maxpower.com",
    infoPersonal: {
      nombre: "Homero Simpson",
      direccion: {
        calle: "Avenida Siempreviva",
        numero: 742,
        barrio: "Springfield",
        estado: "Massachusetts",
      },
    },
  };
  
  var objContains = function (obj, prop, value) {
  for (propiedad in obj) {
    if (propiedad === prop && obj[propiedad] === value) {
      return true;
    } else if (typeof obj[propiedad] === 'object') {
      obj = obj[propiedad];
      return objContains(obj, prop, value); //-->Aqui faltaba el return 
    }    
  } 
  return false; //--> Este return debe ir despues del for, no al final de él.
}

console.log(objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield")) // Al ejecutar esta el resultado debe ser true

console.log(objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear"));// al ejecutar esta debe ser false
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo ha funcionado correctamente. :)

Comment: @Hamiltonps si te funcionó, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada presionando la marca de verificación (✔) que se encuentra a la izquierda de la respuesta.